# Sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}[\frac{x(x+n)}{n}]^n$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Consider series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}[\frac{x(x+n)}{n}]^n$. Find all values of $x$ such that the series is convergent.

I'm thinking about using the geometric series. to make the series convergent I need to have

$$|\frac{x(x+n)}{n}|<1\:\:\text{for all }\:\:n\in \mathbb{N}.$$

Hence I think $|x|<1$, but actually I'm looking for the exact sum of the series. I appreciate any hint.

Comment: the series is not a geometric series

Comment: You may use root test. Then you can get radius of convergence. Also you should check the boundary points.

Comment: You don't need your inequality for all $n$, just for $n$ large enough.  Convergence never depends on the early terms because they always have a finite sum.

Comment: The only case which is unclear is $\,x=-1\,$ . But it’s $\,\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty ((-\frac{n-1}{n})^n-\frac{(-1)^n}{e})\approx 0.2923…\,$ convergent and therefore your series is divergent for $\,x=-1\,$ (or simply: your series for $x=-1$ has no sequence to zero - an obligatory condition for convergence of series) .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you could find a uniform bound looking like

$$\left|\frac{x(x + n)}{n}\right| \le r < 1$$

then you'd be set, after comparing to a geometric series. Notice that

$$\left|\frac{x(x +n)}{n}\right| \le |x|\left(1 + \frac{|x|}{n}\right).$$

Now provided that $|x| < 1$, choose $n$ large enough that this quantity is strictly less than $1$, for example something like $n > x^2 / (1 - |x|)$. All subsequent terms can be compared with a geometric series, and there are only finitely many preceeding terms. Hence the series is convergent for $|x| < 1$. Using a similar technique, you can study what happens when $|x| > 1$.

If $x = 1$, it is clearly divergent. If $x = -1$, we have

$$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{n - 1}{n}\right)^n$$

and the terms tend to $e^{-1}$, not zero.

Answer (score 1):

Cauchy criterion: the positive terms series converges if

$\lim_{n\to \infty } \, \sqrt[n]{a_n}<1$

In our series

$\lim_{n\to \infty } \, \left|\dfrac{x (n+x)}{n}\right|=|x|$

so the series is convergent if $|x|<1$ and is divergent for $|x|>1$

There is no formula for the sum of the series in the general case.

Hope this helps

Edit

The series for $x=1$ becomes $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^n$ which clearly diverges because the general term $a_n\to e$ doesn't tend to zero

for $x=-1$ the series becomes $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }(-1)^n \left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^n$

this is an alternating series which according to the Leibniz criterion  diverges

$\lim_{n\to \infty } \, \left(\dfrac{n-1}{n}\right)^n=\frac{1}{e}\ne 0$

Comment: What happens if $|x|\geqslant1$? The OP asks this and you omit it altogether, why?

Comment: After silent Edit, you still do not prove divergence for $|x|=1$. Actually, now the post is written in a way that makes believe you applied a criterion for divergence, which happens to be **wrong**. The game is not supposed to be to mislead the readers...

Comment: @Did Thank you for your feed back

Comment: @Did anyway for $x=-1$ Mathematica gives $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } (-1)^n \left(\dfrac{n-1}{n}\right)^n\approx 0.108421$.

Comment: @Did The previous value is the Cesàro sum of the series. As $n\to\infty$ positive and negative values tend to cancel. It's what happens to $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }  \sin n$ which has a nice closed Cesàro sum $\frac{1}{2} \cot \left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)\approx 0.91524$

Comment: Now we know what happens at $x=1$ and at $x=-1$. FYI, the series $\sum(-1)^n\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)^n$ is **not** alternating, please check the definition of "alternating series".

Comment: @Did In mathematics, an alternating series is an infinite series of the form

    $\sum _{{n=1}}^{\infty }(-1)^{{n-1}}\,a_{n}$

with $a_n > 0$ for all $n$. What is going wrong FMI?

Comment: Simply that you forgot a condition, as careless readers do.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is a closed form, but you can derive some asymptotics.

The general term is $x^n\left(1+\dfrac xn\right)^n$ where the second factor can be approximated by

$$e^x-\frac12 e^xx^2\frac1n+\frac1{24}e^xx^3(3x+8)\frac1{n^2}-\cdots$$

After summation this gives

$$\frac{xe^x}{1-x}+\frac12 e^xx^2\log(1-x)+\frac1{24}e^xx^3(3x+8)\text{Li}_2(x)+\cdots$$